# CSS div width not working

Tags: css, width

I have a strange problem.One of my div's width is not working. My CSS is like

```
.product_info
{
    margin-top:10px;
    background:#444;
    width:850px;

}
.product_image
{
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    background:#fff;
}
.product_details
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    background:#d71414;
}
```

And My HTML file is

```
<div class="product_info">
                <div class="product_image">

                </div>

                <div class="product_details">
                    <div class="selection">
                    <form action="{$path_site}{$indeex_file}" method="post">
                    Size
                    {foreach name = feach item = k from = $product_size}
                        <input type="radio" name="size" value="{$k.product_size}" />{$k.product_size}
                    {/foreach}


                    </div>

                    <div class="selection">
                    No. of pieces <input type="text" name="quantity">

                    </div>
                    <div class="prc">
                        <span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> {$product_info->product_cost}.00
                            </div>

                    <div class="buy_btn"><input type="submit" value="BUY" /></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But as you can see in the attached image my `div` `product_info`'s width is not `850px`, Whats wrong[image]

Comment: Put your code in a jsFiddle, so we could all test it... 
Have you checked it in other browsers too?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try

display:block

It should work

Comment: You can also do `display:inline-block` if you want other elements to be inline.

Comment: can you please also explain your solution?

Answer (score 92):

`display: flex` **on the parent element** also changes how `width` and `height` work. Disable shrinking/growing by `flex: 0 0 auto;`, or use `min-width` and `max-width` instead.

Width and height basically lose the original meaning in this context and will act as a `flex-basis`, see [geddski: The Difference Between Width and Flex Basis](http://gedd.ski/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/)

```css
.box {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
.box.gray {
  background: lightgray;
}
.box.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 80%;
">
  <div>
      width: 300px;
  </div>
  <div class="box container">
    <div class="box gray" style="width: 200px;">
      width: 200px;
    </div>
    <div class="box gray" style="width: 200px;">
      width: 200px;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box container">
    <div class="box gray" style="
      width: 200px;
      flex: 0 0 auto;
    ">
      width: 200px;<br>
      flex: 0 0 auto;
    </div>
    <div class="box gray" style="width: 200px;">
      width: 200px;
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :)  flex: 0 0 auto probably the best for this case

Comment: I just spent two hours troubleshooting why the width of my flex item was not 30% of its parent using variations of `width` property. `flex: 0 0 30%;` finally did the trick!

Comment: `flex: none` = `flex: 0 0 auto`

Answer (score 4):

`display: inline-block;` Worked for me

Example:

```
label {
    min-width: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/MU2CUpre

Actually you have used `floating` in your `child div's` and didnt `clear` your `parent div`.
So i have `cleared` your `parent div` through `overflow:hidden;` in **parent div** and `cleared` this child div `.product_details` also its working fine......

**CSS**

```
.product_info
{
    margin-top:10px;
    background:#444;
    width:850px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.product_details
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    background:#d71414;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: The link you provided is broken

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clear: both;` property.

```
.product_info {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi now define your class `.product_into`  `overflow:hidden;`

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/fTZb7JgP)***

as like this

```
.product_info{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

## =======

**or option 2**

define one css

**Css**

```
.clr{
clear:both;
}
```

Put the this `div` in last line **closing** the `.product_info` **class**

```
<div class="product_info">
                <div class="product_image">

                </div>

                <div class="product_details">
                    <div class="selection">
                    <form action="{$path_site}{$indeex_file}" method="post">
                    Size
                    {foreach name = feach item = k from = $product_size}
                        <input type="radio" name="size" value="{$k.product_size}" />{$k.product_size}
                    {/foreach}


                    </div>

                    <div class="selection">
                    No. of pieces <input type="text" name="quantity">

                    </div>
                    <div class="prc">
                        <span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> {$product_info->product_cost}.00
                            </div>

                    <div class="buy_btn"><input type="submit" value="BUY" /></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                  <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
```

***[Live demo option two](http://tinkerbin.com/N7Qm0GIV)***

Comment: The live demo is not working! Please link a jsFilddle and not paid per click sites!!!